# Debugging phonegap app with weinre with https

Tags: cordova, weinre

My index.html is fetched from the server through an https connection (otherwise I have problems with the oauth procedure).

But the address for the weinre target code is http and not https, therefore for security reasons the browser doesn't load it (at least on desktop chrome, but I assume the same will happen for the inapp browser - is this right?)

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you control the access restrictions on phonegap, adding

`<access origin="http://192.168.1.100" />`

to the config.xml solves this.

(Where the ip address is my debugging computer local network address)

Comment: Ran across this trying to debug a non-phonegap app with weinre, getting the same issue with the browser refusing to load the weinre code since is http, not https.  No idea what the access tag is, but I'm assuming it's phonegap specific and won't work here.   Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm. If you're running the site on a desktop chrome, it has a flag which allows you to do unsafe stuff like this. But you're probably on mobile. If it's chrome-mobile then you can use the built in debugger which allows you to debug the mobile via the desktop). If it's a web view inside a native, than you can do the same as long as you're on android kit kat. Hope this helps

Comment: yeah, i'm on mobile, using a browser, not a web view.  i'm trying to do this to avoid the need to have a second (non-mobile) machine to debug on.  my tablet has more than enough specs to do this comfortably.

Comment: This is what I meant: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging
But you probably can't do this on your tablet or another phone...